# How does gallery attribute work

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, attributes, image

I don't understand what the gallery attribute does? I've imported products and images. The images were imported into an attribute called gallery but they don't show up in the admin or on the front-end. They only show if they're placed inside the catalog_product_media_gallery table. So, what is the gallery attribute for and why did Magento put my images into that field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong attribute I think. Those values should have been imported to the `media_gallery`attribute.

Comment: Well, a gallery attribute does exist and it's label is Image Gallery. That is the confusing. What does gallery do that media_gallery or the DB table doesn't do

Comment: *"What does gallery do that `media_gallery` or the DB table doesn't do"* For that, see the record in `eav_attribute` for `image_gallery`, particularly the `backend_model` field value, which processes this attributes values before and after save and after loading: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`.

Comment: @benmarks there is no `image_gallery` attribute. `catalog/product_attribute_backend_media` is the backend model for `media_gallery`. The `gallery` attribute has a null `backend_model`.