# What is the usage of 'gallery' attribute and how it differs from 'media_gallery'

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, media, gallery

`gallery` is a default attribute which ships with Magento along with `media_gallery`, `image`, `thumbnail` and `small_image`. These attributes are grouped under `Images`.

But what is the real use of `gallery` attribute ? We can find specific usage of all other attributes in Magento, but which is not the case of `gallery` attribute.

So I would like to get answer of :

1. What is the usage of `gallery` attribute ?
2. How it differs from `media_gallery` attribute ?

**Edit**

This question is totally different from [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5193), because it is about an import issue. But  here I am asking typically about the usage of a product attribute `gallery`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does gallery attribute work](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/how-does-gallery-attribute-work)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism this is totally a different question. I have already seen referenced question and it is not specifically asking the exact question which I asked above. There OP asks about an import issue which he faced related to galler section. Here the question is specifically related to `gallery` attribute and it's purpose and Ben's answer in referenced question is not all answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery attribute completely differs from media_gallery attribute, gallery attribute is basically your "Image Gallery" i.e. additional images of the product whereas "Media gallery" is where you add videos and other media(except images) related to the product.

I hope it helps, please give kudos and mark this as the answer!

Have a nice day!